# Datatable functions are not working with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable

I'm using Datatable Library to draw table easily.

And I got a data with Fetch API and render to table and It works well. But I don't know why DataTable Funcions like sorting, searching, showing options.

[image]

As you see, get data from API and render to HTML are works well, but when I click sort or search function it changes to this.

[image]

Also Another functions like interval the data from API every 10 seconds and render to table are works well.

It seems that there are some problem in initial state.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './PostContainer.css';

class PostContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableData: {
        status: '0000',
        data: {
          loading: { sell_price: 'loading', volume_7day: 'loading' },
        },
      },
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.getData();
    }, 10000);
  }

  getData() {
    fetch('https://api.bithumb.com/public/ticker/all')
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.json();
        return data;
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          tableData: res,
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    let data = this.state.tableData;
    let chart = [];
    console.log(data);
    if (data.status === '0000') {
      delete data.data['date'];
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.data)) {
        chart.push(
          <tr key={key}>
            <td>{key}</td>
            <td>{value.sell_price}</td>
            <td>{value.volume_7day}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      }
    } else if (
      data.status === '5500' ||
      data.status === '5600' ||
      data.status === '5900'
    ) {
      this.setState({
        tableData: {
          data: {
            ERROR: {
              sell_price: 'ERROR with API',
              volume_7day: 'ERROR with API',
            },
          },
        },
      });
    }
    return (
      <div className="Post">
        <table id="table" className="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Coin Name</th>
              <th>Current Price</th>
              <th>Volume</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{chart}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PostContainer;
```

Can access to [DEMO](https://sangumee.github.io/Crypto-Chart/) directly. I uploaded to Github Pages.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the DataTable component made to be used with react to avoid and reinventing the wheel. Please refer this link:
[Datatable react component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component)

Comment: @AshishAgrahari Thanks I change my component that suggested! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 issue to look for

**a.**

If you see in screenshot there is no Pagination.

When I try load DEMO with Developer Console open.

It works fine and you will see Pagination which will show 10 record at a time.

Check your code for `Datatable` initialization  code in `index.js`

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    order: [[1, 'desc']],
});
```

Make sure above code is called after Data is loaded in HTML

**b.**

Your state value is not updated to actual values while sorting

```
 tableData: {
        status: "0000",
        data: {
            loading: {
                sell_price: "loading",
                volume_7day: "loading"
            }
        }
    }
```